# jQuery - Dynamic Copyright Year

Tags: jquery, date

I have recently been running into alot of my clients coming to me in the last month asking me to update their Copyright on their sites to reflect 2010.

Is it possible to write a small snippet with jQuery that automatically populated the year? When Jan 1st 2011 rolls around, the text would automatically change from 2010 to 2011?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you not use PHP or any server technology? It would be better it dynamic on the server.

Comment: You might want to investigate the legal significance of the year referenced by copyright notices, and the semantics of updating that year simply because a new year has dawned.

Comment: If the copyright notice specifies a year, then it needs to specify the year of first publication, not the current year. Having it auto-update to "now" is a very bad idea as you will end up making an copyright claim.

Comment: Drat, I mean "an incorrect copyright claim" and it is too late to edit it.

Comment: A copyright applies to a creative work.  Machines don't do creative work; people do creative work (often with the assistance of machines).  Therefore, unless you or somebody else does actual work on the website, there's nothing to copyright this year.  Note that IANAL, you haven't mentioned your jurisdiction, and copyright law can get a little arcane.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('#spanYear').html(new Date().getFullYear());
```

The biggest issue being that the client can change the copyright by changing the clock on their own computer ;)

Comment: No jquery: `document.querySelector('#spanYear').textContent = (new Date()).getFullYear()`

Answer (score 2):

You could do it via js but as David suggests its easy to manipulate from the client side. it would be better to stamp it on the server side either directly on your server via php or some other dynamic language (this would require change file extensions or config though) or by using an ajax call to a dynamic file on your server or a time service that wil return the year or full date which you can parse the year out of.

Actually you could use SSI directives for something this simple... REally old tech but the downsides of parsing `.html` as `.shtml` have waaay fewer reprecussions than changing all your file extenstions or parsing `.html` as php or some other language. Assuming SSI is available on the server a simple:

```
<!--#config timefmt="%Y" -->
<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->
```

should do the trick after you make the necessary html -> shtml configuration changes (which i beleive can be done in .htaccess via `AddHandler` or a similar directive).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did with jQuery and I tried to use only one line:

```
&copy; <span id="copyright"> <script>$('#copyright').text(new Date().getFullYear());</script> </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

another possiblity is to make an ajax-call with jQuery to a "time-service" that will return the time/date/year and use that value to update the webpage.

**edit**: [Yahoo has a timeservice](http://developer.yahoo.com/util/timeservice/V1/getTime.html)

Comment: unless OP is actually hosting a site a developer.yahoo.com, wouldn't he need to make a padded JSON request to get that through javascript?

Comment: Cross-domain AJAX is, without any doubt, the easiest and most reliable way to display the current date on a website! ;)

Answer (score 1):

`<script> document.write((new Date()).getFullYear()) </script>`

source: http://the-chronicon.blogspot.com/2015/01/auto-update-of-copyright-year-javascript.html